# CSS3 columns with cutout

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

Is it possible to achieve such layout as on image using css3 columns?

[image]

What we got here is columns of text, but first 2 columns are 'moved down' by title. It also needs to be responsive so no matter how high or wide columns will be - 2 first of them will be 'lowered'.

Basically it could be limited to question - how to apply css to first item in 2nd column of css3 columns container?

Comment: you should try something before asking.. I know you have asked because you dont know the solution.. but you should search something, try and then ask... [Read this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59991/what-are-the-top-issues-when-it-comes-to-low-quality-questions)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use `column-span` in order to have an element span on multiple columns.

Reading the specification
http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-multicol/

I do not see option for your layout request. Probably you should use an hack.

http://jsfiddle.net/8m0phrpf/

CSS

```
.newspaper {
    -webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 3;
}

h2 {
    -webkit-column-span: all; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    column-span: all;
}
```

HTML

**Note:** Internet Explorer 9 (and earlier versions) and Firefox do not support the column-span property.

```
<div class="newspaper">
<h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</h2>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius.
</div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8m0phrpf/1/ - 3rd column should go up again as headline should be 2 columns wide only. column-span basically is like 1 column or all columns span. No way to select only 2.

Comment: Do you have the requirement for a fluid layout?

Comment: http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/graphics/hands-on-css3/hands-on_multi-column.htm

Comment: Yes, layout has to be fluid (fill all screen space)

Answer (score 0):

I made a try, it is not so smart and it could be improved but... I think that is pretty close to the layout in the image.

Basically try to nest 2 different div with 2 column layout each. then use an element to break the content (hr in my example).

This solution leads to other problems (how to place the hr element in the right position in the content? can't imagine how to find a way to place in the right place beside a variation of lenght or font-size of the title)

I leave this answer as a community wiki, maybe someone can improve it

so here's the code:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</h1>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...<hr/> Iure fugit quaerat nisi optio...</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this is the css:

```
h1, hr{
  -webkit-column-span: all;
  column-span: all;
  font-size:2em;
}

hr{visibility:hidden;}

div.child, div.parent{
  -webkit-columns: 2 ;
  -moz-columns: 2;
  columns: 2;
}
```

you can see it working in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yL4zyx1p/

Comment: Well... at the end it leads to finding right spot in content to divide it. When knowing it, there is a lot of ways to easy do it, but finding such spot (mostly in case when one long p of text is breaked) isnt easy and may not be stable.